# Screen rotate with arrow key(no hot keys are used)

Tags: screen-orientation

Hi I am come across with very interesting issue.
I am using Windows7 32-bit OS.Sometimes whenever I use arrow key it will rotate the screen .I don't know why it is behaving like this. It will happen frequently .Does any one have idea about this.
Please suggest.

Comment: Alt Gr + arrow key rotates the screen, maybe your Alt Gr key is broken/pressed?

Comment: Might be better on SU.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Alt-Gr key that's stuck, take a look at this site

http://elv1s.ru/files/js/key-code-detector.html

If the keydown/keyup column says 18 witouth you pressing a key. Your Alt-Gr key is pressed, so it's stuck or broken.

Comment: Its says 18 .that means ALt-Gr key is getting stuck sometime

Comment: Then i advise you to buy a new keyboard or try to fix it: http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Jammed-Keyboard-Key